# C++ interface inheritance different arguments method

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
    int mClassA;
    public:
    A() : mClassA(1) {}
    void print() override { std::cout << "print A" << std::endl; }
    void foo( A& arg ) { std::cout << mClassA << std::endl; }
};

class B : public Base
{
    int mClassB;
    public:
    B() : mClassB(2) {}
    void print() override { std::cout << "print B" << std::endl; }
    void foo( B& arg ) { std::cout << mClassB << std::endl; }
};
```

So I got class structure similar to this. What approach should I take to call foo without dynamic_cast each time?

```
int main()
{
  Base * obj1 = new A();
  Base * obj2 = new A();
  dynamic_cast<A*>(obj1)->foo(*dynamic_cast<A*>(obj2));
}
```

I could create foo method with base class argument but I want to be sure that I'm passing A or B obejct as an argument.

Comment: Can you use a virtual function `virtual void foo()`?

Comment: `I could create foo method with base class argument but I want to be sure that I'm passing A or B obejct as an argument.` You can't even create an instance of `Base`, so what exactly do you mean by this sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You could use templates to make sure that a particular parameter of one of the class' member functions has at least a particular type. See the following code illustrating this:

```
template <class P>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int nr) : mClass(nr) {}
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual void foo( P& arg ) { std::cout << mClass << std::endl; }
protected:
    int mClass;

};

class A : public Base<A>
{
public:
    A() : Base(1) {}
    void print() override { std::cout << "print A" << std::endl; }
    virtual void foo( A& arg ) override { Base::foo(arg); cout << "is A for sure" << endl; }
};

class B : public Base<B>
{
public:
    B() : Base(2) {}
    void print() override { std::cout << "print A" << std::endl; }
    virtual void foo( B& arg ) override { Base::foo(arg); cout << "is B for sure" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Base<A> * obj1 = new A();
    A* obj2 = new A();
    obj1->foo(*obj2);

    Base<B> * objb1 = new B();
    B* objb2 = new B();
    objb1->foo(*objb2);

//  objb1->foo(*obj2);
//  Non-const lvalue reference to type 'B' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'A'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting to do something like this:

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void foo(Base&) = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
    public:
    void foo(A&);
};

class B : public Base
{
    public:
    void foo(B&);
};
```

In object oriented design, this is known as [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_argument_type) (specifically, a "covariant method argument type").

The problem is that this goes against principles of good object oriented design.  The [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) says that, if you have a base class `Base`, then any instances of subclasses of `Base` need to be interchangeable - but you want some subclasses of `Base` to not work with other subclasses of `Base`.  (This is an oversimplification, but there are plenty of discussions online with more detail.)

If you want to do this - if it's the best solution in your case, in spite of the general advice of the Liskov substitution principle - then you can implement the checks yourself.

```
void A::foo(Base& base_arg) {
    // This will throw a runtime exception if the wrong type
    A& arg = dynamic_cast<A&>(base_arg);

    std::cout << mClassA << std::endl;
}
```

Note that you're sacrificing some compile-time type safety now - if you accidentally try to call `A::foo` with an instance of `B`, you won't know until the code runs and you get an exception.  (That's the whole point of virtual functions / dynamic dispatch / polymorphism - the behavior is determined at runtime.)

Another approach would be to use templates, like [@Stephen Lechner's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52265098/25507).  That gives up runtime polymorphism, but it keeps strong type safety and better follows conventional OO design.

The [Wikipedia article on covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_argument_type) has a lot more discussion, including further example code.